# lim sup of the square equals square of the lim sup

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

"Suppose that for the sequence of real numbers {an}, lim sup (an) = c > 0
Prove that lim sup (an^2) = c^2"

For this question, I tried two ways:
1) Since c is the limsup of {an}, given e >0 and k>0, there is an N such that for all n>= N_1, an <= c + k, and for each N, there is an n_1 such that an_1 >= c - k. If we want an^2 <= (c+k)^2 = c^2 + k^2 +2ck <= c^2 + e, then we solve the quadratic inequality: 
k^2 + 2ck - e <= 0. Since k>0, we have 0 < k <= (sqrt(c^2 + e)) - c
Similarly, if we want (an_1)^2 >= (c-k)^2 = c^2 + k^2 - 2ck >= c^2 -e, we need to solve the quadratic inequality:
k^2 - 2ck + e >= 0 
The solution is 
k>= c+sqrt(c^2 -e) OR k<= c - sqrt(c^2 -e); AND k>0. BUT HOW CAN WE MAKE SURE THAT c^2 - e >= 0 must hold???
Also, how to compare the magnitude of 0, c - sqrt(c^2 -e), c+sqrt(c^2 -e), and (sqrt(c^2 + e)) - c ???

The second way I tried is as follows:
2) Let S_N = sup{an | n>=N} for each N,
 then for each fixed N and all n>=N, 
an<=S_N
so since S_N is monotone decrasing with respect to N, and S_N converges to limsup(an) = c >0, we have S_N > 0 for each N.
BUT HOW CAN WE MAKE SURE THAT an >=0 FOR ALL n >=N AND FOR EACH N, so that we can assert:
(an)^2 <= (S_N)^2 ???
Now let's proceed with (an)^2 <= (S_N)^2, for all each fixed N and n >= N.
Then sup(an^2 | n >=N) <= (S_N)^2 for each fixed N
Take limit on both sides of the inequality.
Since for any sequence of real numbers {an}, {bn} such that {an} converges to a and {bn} converges to b, if an<=bn for each n, then we have a=N) <= (S_N)^2 for each N implies that
 lim sup (an^2) <= lim N to infinity: (S_N)^2 = (lim N to infinity: S_N)^2 = (lim sup an)^2 = c^2
however, this only proves that  lim sup (an^2) <= c^2. 
How to prove  lim sup (an^2) = c^2???

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: There is another question which I'm confused about: let {an} be a sequence of real numbers and suppose that limsup(an) is finite. Let {cn} be another sequence and suppose that {cn} converges to c. Prove that if c>=0, then limsup(cn * an) = c*limsup(an)

Comment: Can you try to use $\LaTeX$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem as stated is incorrect.

For example, if we let $a_n=\begin{cases}-2, & \text{if n is odd} \\ 1+\frac{1}{n}, & \text{if n is even} \end{cases}$

then $\limsup a_n =1$, but $\limsup \;(a_{n})^2=4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem states that lim sup (an) = c > 0. Your counter example has limsup(an) < 0...

Comment: I think this counterexample is all right, since $\limsup a_n=1>0$

Comment: Thanks! But in my problem, it says "limsup{an}=c > 0" In this case, the statement would be correct, right?

Comment: No, I don't think it is correct:  $\limsup a_n=1>0$ in this case, but $\limsup (a_n)^2\ne1^2$.  If the problem specified that $a_n\ge0$ for all n, then I think it would be correct.